# How I am to pass specific xml fragment, which the i save in variable, in <xsl:call-template>?

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

I need save  node and pass this node in <xsl:call-template name="update.target">, how i can do this ?  I searched for information on the Internet, I could not find

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year lol="1">1985</year>
  </cd>
<cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <target>
      <first>Jane</first>
      <second>Lane</second>
    </target>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html> 
<body>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="catalog">
  <xsl:if test="cd/target">
    <xsl:call-template name="update.target">
     <!-- pass <target> node in update.target template -- >
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="update.target">
 ... do something
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I try use xsl:param and xsl:with-param, but I could not.

Comment: Well I would suggest to forget about `xsl:call-template` and named template and simply use template matching (e.g. `xsl:template match="target"`) and push processing (e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="cd/target"/>`). But anyway, you can select `cd/target` and pass it on e.g. `<xsl:with-param name="target" select="cd/target"/>`. Perhaps show us exactly what you tried and how it failed.

Comment: The example is somewhat confusing, because the input can contain more than one `target` element, so passing `cd/target` as the parameter may pass more than just a "specific XML fragment". Note also that calling a template does not change the context, so it's possible you do not have to pass anything. It all depends on what the template is supposed to do - but you did not tell us anything about that.

Comment: @michael.hor257k that is what it says to me: *pass <target> node in update.target template*

Comment: @MartinHonnen to use  xsl:template match target would be not exactly what is aked. xsl:with-param should be used, otherwise it will not be passed to the template as a snippet.

Comment: @MJG The question is not what it says to you, but what it is the real purpose here. This has all the warning signs of being an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Yes, I see that the phrasing of the question is a little bit confusing. Still to me it is pretty obvious that the select in a matching template will not be the desired solution when you try to pass it to a named template (as stated several times now). Thus, only in my opinion maybe, a select/matching here would barely work.

Comment: @MJG, why would `<xsl:template match="catalog"><xsl:apply-templates select="cd/target"/></xsl:template><xsl:template match="target">..do something</xsl:template>` not work? What do you pretend to gain by using named templates and verbose `xsl:call-template/xsl:with-param`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different changes to be considered.

1. Introduce param to the template output.target:

```
<xsl:template name="update.target">
    <xsl:param name="target" />
```

2. Pass some target to updated.target:

```
        <xsl:if test="cd/target">
            <xsl:call-template name="update.target">
                <xsl:with-param name="target" select="cd/target"/>
```

3. To output the passed param, you can use value-of:

```
        <xsl:value-of select="$target/first/text()" />
```